# Some questions about implementing Swendsen-Wang algorithm

Tags: statistical-thermodynamics, monte-carlo, ising-model

I have a lattice system with two types of sites, namely A and B. Both A and B have a possible up or down spin orientation. There exists  $J_\textrm{aa,align}/J_\textrm{aa,mis}$, $J_\textrm{bb,align}/J_\textrm{bb,mis}$, and $J_\textrm{ab,align}/J_\textrm{ab,mis}$ interactions in my system between nearest neighbors. There is no external field.

I am following the notes given [here](https://csml.northwestern.edu/resources/Reprints/lnp_color.pdf) [1].

I want to employ Swendsen-Wang evolution for this problem, and **I wanted to know if I can form "bonds" between A and B sites? Is that rigorously possible? Or is do sites of type A only bond with sites of type A, and likewise for B?**

**References:**

1. Computer Simulations in Condensed Matter Systems: From Materials to Chemical Biology Volume 1. *Lect. Notes Phys.* **2006**. [DOI: 10.1007/3-540-35273-2](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-35273-2).

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I'm just here to ask why the statistical-thermodynamics tag wasn't appropriate here, since it's used in so many of your other questions!

Comment: Sorry for the late response @NikeDattani. I will add this tag right now

Comment: I was just curious about why it wasn't there :)

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the derivation of the Swendsen-Wang method as described on Wikipedia ([1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swendsen%E2%80%93Wang_algorithm)), you will see that it works whether the quantity $J_{nm}$ is same for all links or different for different kinds of links.

So you should bond / unbond all nearest neighbour interactions as per the method. You must simply ensure that the bonding probability for each link is correctly related to that particular link's ferromagnetic coupling strength.